# PHP - Зачитать строку из файла

Tags: php

Строка в файле \x86
Считываем и помещаем в переменную $test_string.
Не получается привести переменную к виду "\x86"
var_damp($test_string) / string(6) "\x86 "
var_damp("\x86")  / string(1) "�"
Необходимо для декодирования строк.
Вопрос простой, но все мои манипуляции с двойными кавычками, окончились неудачей.
Cтрока набранная руками в коде, к примеру "\x68\x9A\x9A\x68\x08\x33\x72\x51\x05\x33\x58\xA5\x11\x40\x16" - обрабатывается декодирующей программой.
Аналогичная строка полученная из файла не обрабатывается.
Управляющие последовательности в ней не срабатывают и представляются в виде '\x68\x9A\x9A\x68\x08\x33\x72\x51\x05\x33\x58\xA5\x11\x40\x16'

Comment: я одного не понял - при чем здесь двойные кавычки-то?

Comment: и ещё я не понял, чего мы хотим добиться, выводя "var_damp("\x86")"

Comment: при том что задача решается примитивно

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста примитивное решение

Comment: hex2bin() а дальше сам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может все же наоборот? "\x86" это символ с кодом 86.

Чтобы получить именно эту строку, необходимо косую экранировать:

```
$var = "\\x86";
```

Для преобразования строковой записи кода символа в сам символ можете восползоваться следующим методом:

```
<?php
$var = "\\x77 просто буквы \\x5A"; // пример строки
var_dump($var);
preg_match_all('/\\\x([0-9A-F]{2})/', $var, $matches); // Используя данное регулярное выражение выбираем все конструкции вида \xDD 
var_dump($matches);  // Выведем все совпадения
foreach($matches[1] as $val){ // почему именно [1] читайте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php
  echo $val."='".hex2bin($val)."'\n"; // выведем строковое представление и сам символ
}
?>
```

Если потребуется заменить искомые коды в строке, используйте флаг PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE и в цикле заменяйте matches[0][i] на hex2bin(matches[1][i])

Comment: Увы, мне необходимо получить из файла именно "�" для декодирующей программы.

Comment: дополнил ответ. постарайтесь более понятно формулировать вопросы. удачи!

Comment: господи, да зачем здесь регулярка-то? и если уж городить её, то хотя бы правильную

Comment: Сергей, спасибо большое. hex2bin() решила задачу)